# Learning to write a gazebo plugin... where to start?

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'll try and be blunt:

My goal is to code what is left to build a simulator using ROS and Gazebo for the Lego NXT. Over the last <del>weeks</del> months I've been trying to learn as much as I could of how does ROS work, focusing on the tutorials that are available on the wiki.

Right now I'm trying to understand how gazebo plugins work, but I'm trying to achieve that by following the PR2 tutorials (and the plugins that are behind them), and they (plugins, not tutorials) seem to be too complex for me to understand them and write my own.

Back on September Tully Foote gave me [a link](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/simulator/file/d76b1532b281/turtlebot_gazebo_plugins) with an example plugin (create_plugin) that I'm looking into right now, but I don't really know what does it actually do, so it's difficult for me to understand it.

Of course, I've tried (without luck) to find answers to my questions on this pages first, so any help will be welcome. Meanwhile I'll keep trying by myself :)

Thanks, Miguel.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12677/learning-to-write-a-gazebo-plugin...-where-to-start?/) by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2012-01-18

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-01-24**:
I didn't see this. I didn't know how to just close the question so I added an answer. But now I can't accept my own answer...

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-01-19**:
Since the other was answered can you close the question?

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-01-18**:
I just updated your plugin reference (http://bit.ly/z72dZk) with links to the new gazebo plugin API documentation.  Let me know if the documentation is helpful or needs improvements.

**Comment by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) on 2012-01-18**:
Right after writing these lines I've found this answer http://bit.ly/z72dZk and I'm trying that approach, but if you have any other resources they'll be welcome, as I said :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Answered here: http://bit.ly/z72dZk

---

Originally posted by [Capelare](https://answers.ros.org/users/967/capelare/) with karma: 202 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2